# Making ocean loop hexagonally

Tags: ocean-simulation

I am creating objects for a game which consists of hexagonal tiles. I successfully created looping animation for ocean, but failed to make it loop spatially, due to my tile being hexagon, and not a rectangle. As a result, my water objects don't fit together nicely:

[image: Group of water tiles, it is easy to see discern separate objects.]

Is this "hexagonal looping" possible in blender?

[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fhs81ijd4688t5/hexagon.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to keep your mesh as hex tiles? Or else you can use  CTRL + T to triangulate all the faces.

Comment: @hawkenfox Yes, the game mechanics have been built around a hexagonal game grid. Due to how the tiles work, it is necessary that each tile's projection on a horizontal plane be a regular hexagon. All faces are already triangulated, as my rendering engine does not allow non-triangle faces.

Comment: I see , is it possible to post a .blend file with just a portion of the mesh in question so some of us could diagnose the problem and probably solve it.

Comment: @hawkenfox added blend file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a hexagon grid converted to a staggered rectangular grid with indication of the direction how the rectangles need to *"line up"*:

[image]

The rectangles are seamless from top to bottom exactly how you expect. But the left-right 'seamlessness' needs to be rotated +30°(or -30°) because of the staggering.

When you have the rectangle seamless, you create the hexagon from it by cutting and re-arranging the corners like this:

[image]

Now you know how to seamlessly tile hexagons. With a bit of skill you don't need to go through the rectangle phase at all, just create **tiling with one tiling axis rotated 30°**. That's the trick.